# nothing in Laravel job handle() except the notification is working?

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, laravel-8, laravel-queue

The mail notification sending code written in the `handle` method of the job works. But except that , no other line of codes work there. Even doing `dd("hi")` in the `handle()` not gives me any result. In the below code, inside the `handle()` i've written to update the `status` column of `$this->user` to `true` .But it's not working there  although `dd($this->user)` inside the `constructor` gives me an array of data including the status field. Any help to resolve this is much appreciated.

**Job**

```
class SendEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $user;
    public $msg;
    
    public function __construct($msg,$data)
    {
        $this->user=$data;
        $this->msg = $msg;
       // dd($this->user);
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        //dd("hi");
        $this->user->update(['status' => 'true']);
        $not=Notification::send($this->user, new courseAddedNotification($this->msg));
        //dump($not);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use dd then you have to change ENV.

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
```

If the feature you perfect use the command

```
  php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default
```

Comment: if i have given so, jobs will not be pushed to db. so, i kept `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database`

Comment: If you want to use dd then you have to change ENV.
If the feature you perfect use the command
php artisan queue: work --queue = high, default

Comment: ur answer is not clear. Pls give me a meaningful sentence. I didn't understand the meaning of ur comment

Comment: So think you should use sync for debugging before database switch.

Comment: for what , u recommended to use this command-  `php artisan queue: work --queue = high`

Comment: I used to give `php artisan queue: work` commnad

Comment: Am facing 1 more problem also. When changing `QUEUE_CONNECTION` to `sync`, the job is not dispatched. So, I can't debug & see what is coming in this line - `Notification::send($this->user, new courseAddedNotification($this->msg));`  ,as this returns `null` when the job is not dispatched. When `QUEUE_CONNECTION` IS `database`, job gets dispatched. But we can't `dd()` the output , know? What can i do here?

Comment: You can dispatch work in 1 route and access browser for debugging.

Comment: can u tell it clearly? How to  debug it with browser ? i kept `Queue_cconnection=database` & run `php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default` .And tried `print_r($not)`. Nothing dispalyed in browser although the job processed successfully.

Comment: No errors seems to be logged in to the laravel.log